# How to retain/restore scroll position on infinite scroll page?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i have an infinite scroll page in my nextjs app where i can't restore the scroll position when clicking browser back button.

i am fetching the data in getServersideProps

```
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('/api');
  const data = await res.json();
  return { props : { data} }
}
```

i have a hook for scroll pagination

```
    const { useState, useEffect } = require("react");

const useInifiniteScroll = (callback) => {
    const [ isFetching,setIsFetching ] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll' , handleScroll);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll',handleScroll);
    },[])
    useEffect(() => {
        if(!isFetching) return;
        callback(() => {
            console.log('called back')
        })
    },[isFetching])
    function handleScroll() {
        if(window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop ===
            document.documentElement.offsetHeight / 2 || isFetching) return;
        setIsFetching(true)
    }
    return [ isFetching, setIsFetching ];
}

export default useInifiniteScroll;
```

and i have a useEffect method to fetch the rest of the api.and i will merge both api's together to a common state variable.

so here if i am navigating to next route,how can i restore the previous scroll position?

Comment: Stuck in same situation. Any luck ?

Comment: Hi @gurupalsingh, can you elaborate on the issue?

Comment: I have one product listing page with infinite scroll pagination. Whenever i click on any of the product and goto product detail page and then press browser back button, it will takes me to bottom of the page instead of where i was. What should i do to retain by old state ?

Comment: First you have to cache your api responses and then you have to store the scrollposition by using window.scrollX and window.scrollY,its good if you are storing it on sessionstorage and then on router load you have to call them.

Comment: Are you doing it on React or using any framework such as NextJS?

Comment: @gurupalsingh Also you can use react-query or use-swr for caching,Both of them are good and provides you unique solutions

Comment: yes i am using gatsbyjs